# Application Life Cycle Management

Tags: excel, vba, alm

We connect ALM using OTA connection library but our company added "2FA" two factor authentication as a security using Symantic VIP access for every outside employee who will access our ALM so what I need now is to add this 2FA authentication in the following previous code to work well as previous.

```
Private Function TDConnect_ServerConnect(ByVal strServer As String)

    On Error GoTo ErrCatch

    If (g_objTDC Is Nothing) Then Set g_objTDC = New TDConnection

    If (g_objTDC Is Nothing) Then
        TDConnect_ServerConnect = TDCONNECT_STATUS_FAIL
    Else
        g_objTDC.InitConnectionEx strServer
        TDConnect_ServerConnect = TDCONNECT_STATUS_PASS
    End If

Exit Function

ErrCatch:
    TDConnect_Log Err.description, LOG_ERROR
    TDConnect_ServerConnect = TDCONNECT_STATUS_FAIL

End Function
```

Comment: So, what is the question exactly? [please provide a clear explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i need to know how to implement 2FA authentication in code so users could use the same without any error regarding this 2FA.

Comment: What problem do you have right now when you run this code with TFA?. It's quite possible that it simply works as normal.